# Instalando apk de um app a partir de outro app já instalado

Tags: android, mobile

Após pesquisa não encontrei nada recente ou específico sobre isso, então resolvi perguntar aqui.
Na empresa em que trabalho temos algumas soluções móveis e diferentes clientes usam diferentes conjuntos de Apps. Assim, nos foi requerido que escrevêssemos uma aplicação que deve ser capaz de instalar os apks (e eventualmente atualizar) dos outros apps do nosso ecossistema no aparelho, tudo sem a interação do usuário. Bom, sei que nas configurações do device posso indicar o app com permissão para instalação, mas ainda assim, pelo que sei, o usuário precisa interagir.

Gostaria de saber se isso é possível de ser feito sem que o usuário participasse do processo e qual seria o caminho, caso possam indicar algum material mais detalhado.

Muito obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Se não me engano, as versões mais recentes do Android não permitem a instalação de um APK sem confirmação, mesmo que você libere o aplicativo para realizar instalações.

Comment: @RafaelTavares muito obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Instalar apks por fora da store tem que ter permissão Developer liberada no sistema operacional Android (ao menos nas versões mais atuais do sistema creio que seja assim)

Se optar por colocar na play store você pode abrir "um activity" com a playstore, como descrito na documentação
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play

Por exemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

E para evitar abrir esse Activity se o app já estiver instalado você pode usar o [`getApplicationInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getApplicationInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) (que poderá checar se está habilitado também) ou usar simplesmente o [`getInstalledApplications`](http://%5Dhttps://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(int)) e checar na lista

Ou seja, você induz o usuário a instalar via playstore o app se não tiver instalado ainda, assim facilitando e sem precisar de permissões root ou developer.

Eu estou um pouco enferrujado sobre Android, mas creio que com https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller você consegue isso, pois desde a API 29 o [`ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE) [e considerado obsoleto

Provavelmente usando [`installExistingPackage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#installExistingPackage(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.content.IntentSender)) que vai necessitar da permissão [`Manifest.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#INSTALL_PACKAGES) (não deve usar com pacotes de terceiros)

---

Você também pode experimentar o Google play instant:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("id", "com.example.android")
    .appendQueryParameter("launch", "true");

uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("referrer", "exampleCampaignId");

intent.setData(uriBuilder.build());
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

Dessa forma ele nem vai instalar (https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant), no entanto o app que vai usar esse serviço precisa seguir uma série de situações para ser disponibilizado como Instant: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/guides/reduce-module-size

Comment: Obrigado pela riqueza de detalhes Guilherme. Vou experimentar as opções que deu e ver qual delas seria mais viável para o cliente. Grande abraço.